# VB6 Focus Glow Effects

Tags: vb6

I have a form in VB6 with text fields and I would like to create a focus glow like you see in modern web browsers.

Is it possible to make a Glowing Effect in a Textbox using VB6.0?

Kindly give me some advice or way to accomplish this one! Thanks...

Comment: I have no idea what the "glowing effect" that you're describing is. Perhaps if you posted a screenshot? Also, VB 6 isn't used for developing web applications like Facebook. It's designed for desktop programs that run on your local computer. The interfaces for those apps are completely different for a reason. You probably don't need this.

Comment: Im sorry, not Facebook but Twitter

Comment: That doesn't help me any. I don't use either one.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I think he means this:

[Twitter glows](http://www.blog.amruthrajr.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Twitter-type-text-box.jpg)

Comment: @erekalper: That's definitely **not** a Twitter, Facebook, or any other site feature. That's something your web browser does to indicate the text-entry field that currently has the focus. Chrome highlights things in orange; blue is a popular color for other browsers and operating systems.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm aware that it's browser dependent (although the current version of Chrome does in fact highlight the Twitter fields in blue). I was simply trying to illustrate what aerohn was thinking of, since you said you didn't know what he was describing.

Comment: @Cody Gray -- I've updated his question so that hopefully you can understand it a bit better :)

Comment: @slitfy: I appreciate your efforts, but I don't understand where you got the clarification that the original poster means the focus rectangle. That was a different person who posted the screenshot; he was only guessing, also. I could have made assumptions and edited the question myself, but I figured the original asker would come back and clarify it himself. If this *isn't* what he's looking for, it invites a lot of unhelpful and inaccurate answers.

Comment: @Slifty, definitely... Just asking if that effect is possible with VB6. I'm sorry for the ambiguous clarification, I didn't suppose that my query could create a compound interpretation to the readers. @Cody Gray, that is what I'm searching for.

Comment: If that's impossible using VB6, it's OK. I know I've got to face it that the language is too old for this. But as what I said, I'm just TRYING to ask whether it is possible or not... I never intend to bother you sir, just want to improve my project cos it's our school-requirement. Thanks loads for the effort slitfy!

Comment: @Cody Gray -- just call it natural intuition, or the gift of brilliance.  Who am I to know how genius works?  I think Babe Ruth said it best: "Some got it, some don't."  I like to think it comes down to "it was really obvious what he was looking for, you were just being un-necessarily difficult and unhelpful."

Comment: @slifty: Wow, you really enjoy being right. I don't think anything I said deserved that kind of a response. Check my recent answers, I'd say it's pretty inaccurate to call me "unhelpful".

Comment: @Cody Gray I know you're a great contributor to the system, but you came off as somewhat abrasive so I just threw some jovial abrasion back.  Childish of me so I do apologize and of course I also take back the unhelpful.  I'd delete it but I kind of like my fake Babe Ruth quote.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed you are asking other questions regarding modification of the visuals of your VB6 application, too, but you have to face it: VB6 is old, very old and many of the newer UI concepts are very hard to implement in VB6.

Your best shot to make your old VB6 look better is to use a set of more current controls than the original VB6 ones. (Although better look controls are no magic bullet, it's still possible to screw up the UI by making bad layout decisions, for example)

At work we have made good experiences using CodeJock to polish our UI, but even the latest version (15.0.2 at this time) doesn't have a glow effect for text boxes.

Comment: What is the best application sir for this?

Comment: As I said, IMHO CodeJock is a good controls suite, but it's expensive, so best check out the evaluation version first (http://www.codejock.com/downloads/ you need the ActiveX edition) You can also download one of the examples, in your case the Controls demos are the interesting ones: http://www.codejock.com/downloads/samples/controls.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the text box "glow" in Vista/7 by using a manifest. [This manifest creator](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=606736) will handle some of the dirty work for you. Note that the effect will only appear in your compiled app, not running from within the IDE.

Comment: +1 [MakeMyManifest](http://mmm4vb6.atom5.com/) is another manifest maker, it's very popular